# WooCommerce "New Order" report

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking at changing one of our reports, from WooCommerce, the one that comes into the office when we sell something.

To make it easier for us, I'd like the report to show the Price less VAT, it currently shows

```
<th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
```

Does WooCommerce have a standard/default variable name for Price less VAT?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom file in your own plugin OR theme, you should use your own `textdomain` instead of `woocommerce` as it would be easier to maintain and translate through localization.
e.g.

```
<?php _e( 'Price', 'YOUR_TEXTDOMAIN' ); ?>
```